# How to pass an optional argument to \textcite within \newcommand?

Tags: macros, citing

I'd like to define a new command `\mycite` which calls `\textcite`. `\mycite` gets one optional argument. If provided, the argument should appear as an optional argument (`[]`) of `\textcite`. The following MWE shows that `\mycite` without arguments already works, but `\mycite{Section~10}` differs from `\textcite[Section~10]{...}`. `xparse` is probably a solution, but perhaps the below can easily be fixed (?)

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{bib.bib}
@Article{mykey,
   author = {TeX, L.},
   journal = {Journal of LaTeX questions},
   pages = {1--10},
   title = {Minimal title},
   volume = 1,
   number = 1,
   year = 2011
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}
\newcommand*{\mycite}[1][]{\textcite[#1]{mykey}}
\begin{document}
\mycite % without argument; works

\mycite{Section~10} % should behave like the below

\textcite[Section~10]{mykey} % wanted behavior if \mycite was provided with an argument
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\mycite[Section~10] % Optional arguments always in square brackets
```

or define

```
\makeatletter
\def\mycite{\@ifnextchar\bgroup{\my@cite}{\my@cite{}}}
\def\my@cite#1{\textcite[#1]{mykey}}
\makeatother
```

if you want to use `\mycite{Section~10}`

Comment: ah... right... great, thanks!